# CSS fixed position in off-canvas

Tags: html, css, uikit

I have the following issue: using UIkit's off-canvas for showing/hiding a panel to the user with an accordion in it. If there are too much content in the off-canvas panel, a scrollbar appears. That's ok. The issue is with the `Close` button. If I scroll down it "looses" its fixed (to bottom) position and starts scrolling up with the text.
Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Here you can check the Snippet:

```css
.mstr-toolbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.setting-toolbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getuikit.com/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at sapien lacus. Suspendisse imperdiet rutrum tempus. Cras mollis tortor sed dui ultricies, at iaculis magna viverra. Etiam euismod dapibus metus, vitae feugiat urna semper sit amet. Morbi suscipit, enim at pretium porta, ante mauris euismod orci, vel malesuada justo sem ac dolor. Sed gravida neque ac egestas vestibulum. Donec placerat sem eu ornare aliquam. Cras vitae sem quis ipsum maximus condimentum ac in ex. Suspendisse ac rutrum nulla. Proin in finibus lacus. Duis pharetra ligula dui, ut accumsan ipsum viverra maximus. Aliquam auctor sapien velit, nec ornare lectus euismod faucibus.
  </p>
  
  <div class="panel-settings" id="settings" uk-offcanvas="mode: slide; overlay: true; flip: true; container: .container;">
    <div class="uk-offcanvas-bar">
      <ul uk-accordion="multiple: true" id="setAccordion">
        <li class="uk-open">
          <a class="uk-accordion-title" href="#">Accordion #1</a>
          <div class="uk-accordion-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at sapien lacus. Suspendisse imperdiet rutrum tempus. Cras mollis tortor sed dui ultricies, at iaculis magna viverra. Etiam euismod dapibus metus, vitae feugiat urna semper sit amet. Morbi suscipit, enim at pretium porta, ante mauris euismod orci, vel malesuada justo sem ac dolor. Sed gravida neque ac egestas vestibulum. Donec placerat sem eu ornare aliquam. Cras vitae sem quis ipsum maximus condimentum ac in ex. Suspendisse ac rutrum nulla. Proin in finibus lacus. Duis pharetra ligula dui, ut accumsan ipsum viverra maximus. Aliquam auctor sapien velit, nec ornare lectus euismod faucibus. 
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="uk-accordion-title" href="#">Accordion #2</a>
          <div class="uk-accordion-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at sapien lacus. Suspendisse imperdiet rutrum tempus. Cras mollis tortor sed dui ultricies, at iaculis magna viverra. Etiam euismod dapibus metus, vitae feugiat urna semper sit amet. Morbi suscipit, enim at pretium porta, ante mauris euismod orci, vel malesuada justo sem ac dolor. Sed gravida neque ac egestas vestibulum. Donec placerat sem eu ornare aliquam. Cras vitae sem quis ipsum maximus condimentum ac in ex. Suspendisse ac rutrum nulla. Proin in finibus lacus. Duis pharetra ligula dui, ut accumsan ipsum viverra maximus. Aliquam auctor sapien velit, nec ornare lectus euismod faucibus. 
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="uk-accordion-title" href="#">Accordion #3</a>
          <div class="uk-accordion-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at sapien lacus. Suspendisse imperdiet rutrum tempus. Cras mollis tortor sed dui ultricies, at iaculis magna viverra. Etiam euismod dapibus metus, vitae feugiat urna semper sit amet. Morbi suscipit, enim at pretium porta, ante mauris euismod orci, vel malesuada justo sem ac dolor. Sed gravida neque ac egestas vestibulum. Donec placerat sem eu ornare aliquam. Cras vitae sem quis ipsum maximus condimentum ac in ex. Suspendisse ac rutrum nulla. Proin in finibus lacus. Duis pharetra ligula dui, ut accumsan ipsum viverra maximus. Aliquam auctor sapien velit, nec ornare lectus euismod faucibus. 
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="setting-toolbar">
        <button id="btn-close" class="uk-button uk-button-primary" uk-toggle="target: #settings">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mstr-toolbar">
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default">Btn #1</button>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default">Btn #2</button>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-secondary" uk-toggle="target: #settings">Open panel</button>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default">Btn #3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should add the snippet of code where the problem is.

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your code (html + css) to your question. Please keep the placeholder text to a minimum. Stackoverflow has it's own code editor, similar to jsfiddle now that you can use.

Comment: Ok, I put this all in an html, and it doesn't appear to be working as should. Would you like me to try and fix that up or would you rather just fix it yourself once you get the answer to this question?

Comment: Thank you for editing. Your problem is related to the transform on your off-canvas bar. If you remove it, the button will stick. The easiest solution would be to rewrite the slide in animation to account for this.

Comment: you want the close button to be positioned at the bottom of the sidebar and flow with content?

Comment: @bowl0stu: exactly. I want the close button to be fixed at the bottom of the sidebar even when I scroll the content down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From your comments, I think you actually want `position: sticky`. Sticky allows a position to be absolutely set inside a container, but follow the viewport if the container scrolls. Unfortunately, this is an experimental implementation. read more about it here, **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky**

By "fixing" the position you mean to keep it always at the bottom of your content. This is a bit confusing given current semantics with css positioning. `position: fixed` (unlike you want) will lock the element to that position relative to the viewport. what you actually want is `position: relative` on your `.setting-toolbar`. This enables it to flow as your content grows/shrinks and keeps it nicely set at the bottom of your container.

```css
.mstr-toolbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.setting-toolbar {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getuikit.com/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at sapien lacus. Suspendisse imperdiet rutrum tempus. Cras mollis tortor sed dui ultricies, at iaculis magna viverra. Etiam euismod dapibus metus, vitae feugiat urna semper sit amet. Morbi suscipit, enim at pretium porta, ante mauris euismod orci, vel malesuada justo sem ac dolor. Sed gravida neque ac egestas vestibulum. Donec placerat sem eu ornare aliquam. Cras vitae sem quis ipsum maximus condimentum ac in ex. Suspendisse ac rutrum nulla. Proin in finibus lacus. Duis pharetra ligula dui, ut accumsan ipsum viverra maximus. Aliquam auctor sapien velit, nec ornare lectus euismod faucibus.
  </p>
  
  <div class="panel-settings" id="settings" uk-offcanvas="mode: slide; overlay: true; flip: true; container: .container;">
    <div class="uk-offcanvas-bar">
      <ul uk-accordion="multiple: true" id="setAccordion">
        <li class="uk-open">
          <a class="uk-accordion-title" href="#">Accordion #1</a>
          <div class="uk-accordion-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at sapien lacus. Suspendisse imperdiet rutrum tempus. Cras mollis tortor sed dui ultricies, at iaculis magna viverra. Etiam euismod dapibus metus, vitae feugiat urna semper sit amet. Morbi suscipit, enim at pretium porta, ante mauris euismod orci, vel malesuada justo sem ac dolor. Sed gravida neque ac egestas vestibulum. Donec placerat sem eu ornare aliquam. Cras vitae sem quis ipsum maximus condimentum ac in ex. Suspendisse ac rutrum nulla. Proin in finibus lacus. Duis pharetra ligula dui, ut accumsan ipsum viverra maximus. Aliquam auctor sapien velit, nec ornare lectus euismod faucibus. 
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="uk-accordion-title" href="#">Accordion #2</a>
          <div class="uk-accordion-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at sapien lacus. Suspendisse imperdiet rutrum tempus. Cras mollis tortor sed dui ultricies, at iaculis magna viverra. Etiam euismod dapibus metus, vitae feugiat urna semper sit amet. Morbi suscipit, enim at pretium porta, ante mauris euismod orci, vel malesuada justo sem ac dolor. Sed gravida neque ac egestas vestibulum. Donec placerat sem eu ornare aliquam. Cras vitae sem quis ipsum maximus condimentum ac in ex. Suspendisse ac rutrum nulla. Proin in finibus lacus. Duis pharetra ligula dui, ut accumsan ipsum viverra maximus. Aliquam auctor sapien velit, nec ornare lectus euismod faucibus. 
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="uk-accordion-title" href="#">Accordion #3</a>
          <div class="uk-accordion-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at sapien lacus. Suspendisse imperdiet rutrum tempus. Cras mollis tortor sed dui ultricies, at iaculis magna viverra. Etiam euismod dapibus metus, vitae feugiat urna semper sit amet. Morbi suscipit, enim at pretium porta, ante mauris euismod orci, vel malesuada justo sem ac dolor. Sed gravida neque ac egestas vestibulum. Donec placerat sem eu ornare aliquam. Cras vitae sem quis ipsum maximus condimentum ac in ex. Suspendisse ac rutrum nulla. Proin in finibus lacus. Duis pharetra ligula dui, ut accumsan ipsum viverra maximus. Aliquam auctor sapien velit, nec ornare lectus euismod faucibus. 
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="setting-toolbar">
        <button id="btn-close" class="uk-button uk-button-primary" uk-toggle="target: #settings">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mstr-toolbar">
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default">Btn #1</button>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default">Btn #2</button>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-secondary" uk-toggle="target: #settings">Open panel</button>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default">Btn #3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, for the confusing stuff, I try to clarify what I want to achieve. So the final goal would be that if I open the off-canvas panel, the close button should be always visible at the bottom corner of the viewport. Now it is ok if the height of the content of the off-canvas is less than the height of the viewport. When I open the accordions and the scrollbar appears and I scroll down that close button should stay at the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks, I accept this as a solution, because I can make what I want based on this :)